# MySQL: How to get the percentage of change of one field compared to a previous one

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a table like this:

```
year | revenue | organisation    
2010 | 83863   | asdf    
2011 | 5463    | asdf
2012 | 45345   | asdf
2009 | 32463   | ghjk
2010 | 352667  | ghjk
```

And I need to search all organisations' latest revenues and up to this point I could build a query like

```
Select new tablename(v.organisation, MAX(v.year), v.revenue) 
from tablename v 
where 1=1 group by v.name
```

But there's still another piece that I need to get, and that's the change of revenue compared to previous year in percent.

How could I do both of those functionalities? Preferably in one query?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT v.organization,
       MAX(v.year) AS currentYear,
       v.revenue,
       ((v.revenue -
           (SELECT i.revenue
            FROM tablename i
            WHERE i.organization = v.organization
              AND i.year = MAX(v.year) - 1)) /
          (SELECT i.revenue
           FROM tablename i
           WHERE i.organization = v.organization
             AND i.year = MAX(v.year) - 1) * 100) AS percentDifference
FROM tablename v
WHERE 1 = 1
GROUP BY v.organization,
         v.year;
```

The sub-select gets the revenue figure from the previous year then it executes the following formula:

```
((currentYearRev - lastYearRev)/lastYearRev) * 100
```

Which should give the percentage difference. I tested it in my environment with your dummy date.

Results:

```
+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
| organization | currentYear | revenue | percentDifference |
+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
| asdf         |        2010 |   83863 |              NULL |
| asdf         |        2011 |    5463 |          -93.4858 |
| asdf         |        2012 |   45345 |          730.0384 |
| ghjk         |        2009 |   32463 |              NULL |
| ghjk         |        2010 |  352667 |          986.3660 |
+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+
```

Results showing the current revenue and the previous years revenue:

```
+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+
| organization | currentYear | revenue | percentDifference | lastRev |
+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+
| asdf         |        2010 |   83863 |              NULL |    NULL |
| asdf         |        2011 |    5463 |          -93.4858 |   83863 |
| asdf         |        2012 |   45345 |          730.0384 |    5463 |
| ghjk         |        2009 |   32463 |              NULL |    NULL |
| ghjk         |        2010 |  352667 |          986.3660 |   32463 |
+--------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for answering to my question. However I noticed that my first query was bad too. I need to use nested select instead to get the row with the maximum year but couldn't solve that yet because this working with objects at mysql is quite new to me.

Comment: Now it's ready so I move on to this part. I left out a ")" and spent an hour trying to figure out why it wasn't good.

Comment: Hope it all works out. Please accept this answer if is does.

Comment: `select v.organisation, v.revenue... group by organisation, year` - looks wrong, right?

Comment: @Strawberry - This work perfectly. I created a database and table and tested it thoroughly. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: Well, you SELECT one thing and then GROUP BY another thing. It's a bit strange.

Comment: That is totally legal in MySQL and also, I selected both of the columns used int he group by. The year is wrapped in the MAX function

Comment: You're pulling an arbitrary revenue - one that necessarily relates to neither year nor organisation.

Comment: There is one revenue per year, the revenue it pulls is not arbitrary but the one associated with a specific org and year--which is why one must group by both org and year

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(year INT NOT NULL
,revenue INT NOT NULL
,organisation VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(year,organisation)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(2010 ,83863   ,'asdf'),
(2011 ,5463    ,'asdf'),
(2012 ,45345   ,'asdf'),
(2009 ,32463   ,'ghjk'),
(2010 ,352667  ,'ghjk');

SELECT x.*
      , ((x.revenue - z.revenue)/z.revenue) * 100 pct_diff
   FROM my_table x
   JOIN
      ( SELECT organisation
             , MAX(year) max_year 
          FROM my_table 
         GROUP 
            BY organisation
      ) y
     ON y.organisation = x.organisation 
    AND y.max_year = x.year
   LEFT
   JOIN my_table z
     ON z.organisation = x.organisation
    AND z.year = x.year - 1;

+------+---------+--------------+----------+
| year | revenue | organisation | pct_diff |
+------+---------+--------------+----------+
| 2010 |  352667 | ghjk         | 986.3660 |
| 2012 |   45345 | asdf         | 730.0384 |
+------+---------+--------------+----------+
```

Here's one (slow) version of a running history...

```
 SELECT x.*
      , ((x.revenue - y.revenue)/y.revenue) * 100 pct_diff
   FROM my_table x
   LEFT
   JOIN my_table y
     ON y.organisation = x.organisation
    AND y.year = x.year - 1
  ORDER 
     BY organisation
      , year;
```

... I'll post a faster alternative if get a moment(/remember how)

Comment: Nicely done. How would you get a running history using this approach? BTW--I 1 upped this.

Comment: Thanks. A running history is a slightly different thing, and I suspect, more memory intensive so I might be tempted to use @variables instead. But I'll try to show examples of both solutions...